# How to use async / await with a method returning an ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I am writing a WPF application using MVVM pattern. I must say I am not (yet) familiar with the .NET async programming model (just learning it) but was writing multi-threaded applications in C/C++ and Java for many years.

The idea is to start long running queries in a separate thread from the UI thread so I have a chance to display a spinner or progress bar while the operation is running.

Most of my internal service methods return collections or other complex types like DTO's etc. The results are usually bound to user controls such as GridViews, ListViews etc. I always get compiler errors saying that my return types do not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'. So I must be doing something wrong.

Here is an example of such a method in my **ViewModel** that calls a service which does a DB query and returns an ObservableCollection.

```
    private async void GetInvoices()
    {
        IsOperationRunning = true; //Binding for a RadBusyIndicator
        Invoices = await _uiContractService.GetInvoices(SelectedInvoiceState, SelectedSupplierItem.Id, SelectedInvoiceDateFilter, FilterStartDate, FilterEndDate);
        IsOperationRunning = false;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Invoices);
        if (Invoices.Count == 0)
            SendUserInfoMsg($"NO invoices matched your search criteria.", UiUserNotificationMessageType.Warning);
    }
```

The compiler error in this case is: 
`ObservableCollection<InvoiceDto>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'ObservableCollection<InvoiceDto>' could be found`

The Invoices collection and the service are declared as

```
    public ObservableCollection<InvoiceDto> Invoices { get; set; }
    var _uiContractService = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<UiContractService>();
```

The signature of the service method is as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<InvoiceDto> GetInvoices(InvoiceState invoiceState, Guid supplierId, UiInvoiceDateFilters dateType, DateTime begin, DateTime end)
```

Any help to guide me into the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: None of the code you have shown returns a task. You need to fix GetInvoices in the service first to be async

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> was writing multi-threaded applications in C/C++ and Java for many years.

This experience is probably misleading you. Asynchronous code is **very** different than multithreaded code.

`await` has nothing to do with threads. Or put another way, it doesn't *increase* the number of threads used; it *decreases* them.

I recommend you first read my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) to get an idea of what `async`/`await` actually do.

Then, you can proceed one of two ways. The first way is *not* ideal, but is what you actually *asked* for:

> The idea is to start long running queries in a separate thread from the UI thread so I have a chance to display a spinner or progress bar while the operation is running.

The first approach is to multithread. In this case, you can use `async`/`await` as a convenient way to retrieve results from an operation running on another thread (including clean, correct exception stacks):

```
private async Task GetInvoicesAsync()
{
  IsOperationRunning = true; //Binding for a RadBusyIndicator
  Invoices = await Task.Run(() => _uiContractService.GetInvoices(SelectedInvoiceState, SelectedSupplierItem.Id, SelectedInvoiceDateFilter, FilterStartDate, FilterEndDate));
  IsOperationRunning = false;
  RaisePropertyChanged(() => Invoices);
  if (Invoices.Count == 0)
    SendUserInfoMsg($"NO invoices matched your search criteria.", UiUserNotificationMessageType.Warning);
}
```

Note that it is the `Task.Run` that introduces multithreading - it schedules work to the thread pool. The `async`/`await` is how the UI thread *pretends* the operation is asynchronous.

This can be called from an event handler (or `ICommand`) as such:

```
public async void EventHandler(object sender, ...)
{
  await GetInvoicesAsync();
}
```

Note that only event handlers should be `async void`. See my [article on `async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more information.

---

But the first approach isn't ideal, because it's not really asynchronous. It's what I call "fake-asynchronous"; that is, the UI is *pretending* it's asynchronous, but the actual operation is just synchronously blocking another thread.

When writing true asynchronous code, it's easier to start at the *other* end - not the top-level UI methods, but the low-level actual API calls. If your services are HTTP services, look into `HttpClient`; if they're WCF services, regenerate your proxies with asynchronous APIs enabled.

Once you have the lowest-level asynchronous APIs available, start using them. Eventually, you'll end up with an asynchronous `GetInvoices`:

```
public async Task<List<InvoiceDto>> GetInvoicesAsync(InvoiceState invoiceState, Guid supplierId, UiInvoiceDateFilters dateType, DateTime begin, DateTime end);
```

(note that I removed `ObservableCollection` from your service layer since it is a UI-oriented type)

Then you can call this method as such:

```
private async Task GetInvoicesAsync()
{
  IsOperationRunning = true; //Binding for a RadBusyIndicator
  Invoices = new ObservableCollection<InvoiceDto>(await _uiContractService.GetInvoicesAsync(SelectedInvoiceState, SelectedSupplierItem.Id, SelectedInvoiceDateFilter, FilterStartDate, FilterEndDate));
  IsOperationRunning = false;
  RaisePropertyChanged(() => Invoices);
  if (Invoices.Count == 0)
    SendUserInfoMsg($"NO invoices matched your search criteria.", UiUserNotificationMessageType.Warning);
}
```

This time, there's no `Task.Run` or any other explicit usage of thread pool threads.

For more details, see the "Transform" parts of my [brownfield `async` article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

Comment: Great post, thanks! My app can run on a single PC or distributed over several machines using an application server. There I use WCF and yes using async API is the way I will chose. For the standalone version I am looking for something, that allows me to inform the user that the software is working and has not crashed if the operation takes longer. I am using DDD patterns for ages. Standalone and n-tier differ mainly by additional DLLs for contracts and some error handling.  In any case your articles and your book may be helpful!

Comment: That's just for the sake of purism... but a single thread doesn't harm. Moreover you are surely I/O bound till the connection is opened but you could start to have CPU spikes once you receive a large amount of data, depending on low latency and large bandwidth... in any case the proxy is a "fake" facade as well with regards to the server side implementation of the service.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary, how would changes in the ContractService be reflected in this UI collection? Suppose the ContractService can be invoked from other contexts (.e.g. Add/update of invoices from background threads)?

Comment: @Werner: First, I try to structure my code so that updates from other services aren't extermally-sourced. E.g., a user-initiated refresh or even a poll can be sourced from the UI thread, and then can use `async` naturally. However, for those rare cases where another thread (or system) can *push* updates to my UI app, I prefer to use `SynchronizationContext` to switch to the UI and then update the `ObservableCollection` or other possibly-data-bound entities.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary thanks. I've been using your articles so far with success. Do you by any chance have an article (or know of one) about how to pass the SynchronizationContext from UI down to a service? I have a use case where telemetry data is arriving from hardware and I need to bubble these into a UI graph from my service (services and viewmodels are created by my IoC container).

Comment: I don't, sorry. You should be able to grab `SynchronizationContext.Current` and pass that down. Some components do capture it in their constructor, though I strongly recommend documenting this if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should return a [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public Task<ObservableCollection<InvoiceDto>> GetInvoices(InvoiceState invoiceState, Guid supplierId, UiInvoiceDateFilters dateType, DateTime begin, DateTime end)
{
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is GetInvoices doing anything async? If it is, its signature should be:

    `public async Task<ObservableCollection<InvoiceDto>> GetInvoices(InvoiceState invoiceState, Guid supplierId, UiInvoiceDateFilters dateType, DateTime begin, DateTime end)`.
If you aren't, then you shouldn't worry about async and remove the async/await keywords from the outer `GetInvoices` method.

If you want to `await` something, it should return `Task` or `Task<T>`. (I won't even go into async void methods).

Answer (score 0):

You con do a "fake" asynchronous task out of your GetInvoices:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<InvoiceDto>> GetInvoicesAsync(InvoiceState invoiceState, Guid supplierId, UiInvoiceDateFilters dateType, DateTime begin, DateTime end)
{
    return await Task.Run( () =>
    {
         return GetInvoices(invoiceState, supplierId, dateType, begin, end);
     });
}
```

This could be considered bad code, here it's simply to show how you can make it formally await-able by calling the method with Async suffix

Anyway this is wpf, not a asp.net or a web app. So if it's a pure desktop GUI, it would make sense to run a db task in background. It's more problematic if that were on an application server and not on a client..

```
    Invoices = await _uiContractService.GetInvoicesAsync(SelectedInvoiceState, SelectedSupplierItem.Id, SelectedInvoiceDateFilter, FilterStartDate, FilterEndDate);
```

Notice that there is a big difference between a wrong and a not ideal thing and that it is not always the case that you can have immediate support for an upgrade to the latest technology.

Another point that you're not asking but looks odd is how you raise property changed.
A much more convenient place is the setter of the property.
 Then you don't need to call it after an assignment unless you are using the underlying private member.

I would have also cleaned the collection before just to enphasize the work in progress but these are personal preferences.

Comment: You don't even need to do that much, instead use `Task.FromResult(TResult)`: Creates a `Task<TResult>` that's completed successfully with the specified result.

Comment: @m-y Which would be completely pointless, and would be a sign that the method shouldn't be asynchronous in the first place.

Comment: Yes, this is not only to make it formally async, but also to let it run in background

Comment: @Servy: I understand, I was merely stating that you could use that in lieu of  the suggested `Task.Run()`.

Comment: @Servy: In terms of bad design or invalid code? I agree, the design is bad (don't make something async when it isn't async), but the code will compile and run.

Comment: @m-y It's writing code that's a lie.  It's misleading, and given that the OP clearly doesn't understand the basics of the subject matter, they won't realize why that's problematic.

Comment: Anyway this is wpf, not a asp.net or a web app. So if it's a pure desktop GUI, it would make sense to run a db task in background. It's more problematic if that were on an application server and not on a client...